# Dart - paper button - how to add onclick script

Tags: dart, paper-elements

I create a paper button dynamically (and add it to the dom tree). Looks fine, but I need to add an action to it by catching an "on pressed" event:

```
  void add_button(String butName){

    PaperButton NewPaperButton=new PaperButton();
    NewPaperButton.text=butName;
    NewPaperButton.style.background='lightgreen';
    NewPaperButton.onClick=callback();<<<<???? what do I do here?? onMouseDown?
```

Cheers
Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the callback like this:

```
void onButtonClicked(Event event, var detail, Element target) {
  // do something
}
```

And you can set up the listener like this:

```
NewPaperButton.onClick.listen(onButtonClicked);
```